# Serialize Custom Attribute Values

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net, custom-attributes

Given the following class:

```
public class PayrollReport
{
    [UiGridColumn(Name = "fullName",Visible = false,Width = "90")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [UiGridColumn(Name = "weekStart", CellFilter = "date")]
    public DateTime WeekStart { get; set; }
}
```

And this custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class UiGridColumn : Attribute
{
    public string CellFilter { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a `List<UiGridColumn>` for each field with only the provided values (I don't want a null for the skipped properties).

Is it possible to create a `List<UiGridColumn>` where each `List` item has only the provided values? (I fear this isn't possible, but thought I would ask) If so, how?

If not, my second preference would be a string array like this:

```
[{"name":"fullName","visible":false,"width":"90"},{"name":"weekStart","cellFilter":"date"}]
```

I would prefer to not loop through each `property` and `attribute` and `argument` to manually build the desired `JSON` string, but I haven't been able to find an easy way to do it otherwise.

```
public List<Object> GetUiGridColumnDef(string className)
{
    Assembly assembly = typeof(DynamicReportService).Assembly;
    var type = assembly.GetType(className);
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    var columnDefs = new List<object>();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var column = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
        var attributes = property.CustomAttributes;
        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            if (attribute.AttributeType.Name != typeof(UiGridColumn).Name || attribute.NamedArguments == null)
                    continue;
            foreach (var argument in attribute.NamedArguments)
            {
                column.Add(argument.MemberName, argument.TypedValue.Value);
            }
        }
        columnDefs.Add(column);
    }
    return columnDefs;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to serialize the list of attributes applied to the properties on a class?

If so, you can make a helper method to do it like this:

```
public static string SerializeAppliedPropertyAttributes<T>(Type targetClass) where T : Attribute
{
    var attributes = targetClass.GetProperties()
                                .SelectMany(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<T>())
                                .ToList();

    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attributes, settings);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
string json = SerializeAppliedPropertyAttributes<UiGridColumn>(typeof(PayrollReport));
```

You will end up with this output, which is pretty close to what you're looking for:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "fullName",
    "Visible": false,
    "Width": "90",
    "TypeId": "UiGridColumn, JsonTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
  },
  {
    "CellFilter": "date",
    "Name": "weekStart",
    "Visible": false,
    "TypeId": "UiGridColumn, JsonTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
  }
]
```

You'll notice the `TypeId` property from the base `Attribute` class is included, and also the property names are not camel cased.  To fix that, you'll need to use a custom contract resolver:

```
public class SuppressAttributeTypeIdResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member.DeclaringType == typeof(Attribute) && member.Name == "TypeId")
        {
            prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Add the resolver to the serialization settings in the helper method and you should be good to go:

```
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        ContractResolver = new SuppressAttributeTypeIdResolver(),
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };
```

Now the output should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "fullName",
    "visible": false,
    "width": "90"
  },
  {
    "cellFilter": "date",
    "name": "weekStart",
    "visible": false
  }
]
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2R5Zyi

Comment: This is almost perfect. `Visible` was defined for only one property, but it shows in both because it is a `bool`. When I try to make it `nullable`, I get `'Visible' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type`. Suggestions?

Comment: You can use `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` in the settings to suppress `Visible` when it is set to its default value of `false`.  However that will also suppress it for the first object, where you had explicitly set it to false.  Unfortunately with this solution you can't have it both ways-- either you always include the value,  or you only include it when it's different from the default.

Comment: Good to know. I am ok with the default values getting skipped. However, I want `Visible` to be `true` by default, so I changed the default value and added the `DefaultValueHandling` code. It works exactly as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, Go Cubs!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you were able to get it working the way you want.  Go Cubs!  :-)