# Serializing(WCF) custom attributes. Is it possible and advisable?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, attributes

I have searched both(Google & here on SO) and the issue is that most questions that do show up have to do with serializing using attributes (XML attributes or DataContract), not the actual serialization of custom attributes. See below for the few questions that were similar

We are in the planning stages of a certain project.

One of the requirements has led us to question **if possible and advisable to serialize(for WCF) custom attributes.**

**If so, do we also need KnownType attributes decorating the service contract?**

For example, we have the custom attribute, used in our DTO objects:

```
  [DataContract] // <- is this allowed/adviseable
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
  public class DtoPropertyAttribute : Attribute
  {
    [DataMember] // <- this too
    public int MaximumLength { get; set; }

    public DtoPropertyAttribute(int maximumLength)
    {
      this.MaximumLength = maximumLength;
    }   

  }
```

At some point we then use...

```
Object[] GetCustomAttributes(bool inherit);
```

...from namespace:

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo
```

...as follows on (the WCF service end):

```
 //property is of type System.Reflection.ProperInfo
 var attributes property.GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

Then we check if the property has the attribute

```
 //..
 //some logic here that iterates/gets a single attribute 'attribute'
 //...

 if(attribute is DtoPropertyAttribute
 {
    //do stuff
 }
```

We noted that Attribute is serializable:

```
namespace System {
// ==++== 
//
//   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
//
// ==--== 

namespace System { 

using System;
using System.Reflection; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts; 
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions; 

    [Serializable] //<--- See me please!!
    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple=false)] 
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(_Attribute))]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
    public abstract class Attribute : _Attribute 
    {
        //...
    }
```

**FOOTNOTE: Similar questions that don't answer my question:**

1. [Serialize Custom Attribute Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211364/serialize-custom-attribute-values) (JSON-related)

Comment: 1) Could you [edit] your question to give an example of the WCF API you want to create?  2) *Is it possible .. to serialize(for WCF) custom attributes?* - have you tried it yet?  What problems did you have?  3) *Is it .. advisable to serialize(for WCF) custom attributes?*  Opinion-based questions are considered off-topic for stackoverflow.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

Wrote a small proof of concept and can happily conclude that attributes(and their values) can be serialized without issue!

**Answer is that it is possible!** Just **DataContract** and **DataMember** decorations on the custom **Attribute** would suffice. No need for **[KnownType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx)** or **[ServiceKnownType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)** decorations.

We will use it and hopefully there are no pitfalls in doing so.

---

### Proof of concept

---

**Interface, DataContract and Attribute:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ServiceTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string TestMethod(ServiceDto dto);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ServiceDto
    {
        [DataMember]
        [DtoProperty(10)]
        public string DtoField { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class DtoPropertyAttribute : Attribute
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int MaximumLength { get; set; }

        public DtoPropertyAttribute(int maximumLength)
        {
            MaximumLength = maximumLength;
        }   
    }
}
```

**Service Implementation:**

```
using System;

namespace ServiceTest
{
    public class Service : IService
    {
        public string TestMethod(ServiceDto dto)
        {
            if (dto == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dto");

            var properties = typeof(ServiceDto).GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
                foreach (var attribute in attributes)
                {
                    var dtoPropAtt = attribute as DtoPropertyAttribute;
                    if (dtoPropAtt != null)
                    {
                        return string.Format("Maximum Length is: '{0}'!" ,dtoPropAtt.MaximumLength);
                    }
                }
            }

            return "Attribute Serialization Test Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Console App with service reference pointing to Web Service Host(AttributeWcfTest)**

```
using System;
using AttributeWcfTest.ServiceRef;

namespace AttributeWcfTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new ServiceRef.ServiceClient();
            var testDto = new ServiceDto()
            {
                DtoField = "Test Value"
            };

            var response = client.TestMethod(testDto);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]